# Animate image with random effects

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have some blocks with images and they need to random animate effects (squares, slides, wave and so on). How i will make it? What Jquery plugins better to use?

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.2my4edge.com/2013/08/image-slider-with-random-animation.html

Comment: look out [this](http://www.jqueryrain.com/?LYI1eiRj) JS library, having much more effects with code.

Answer (score 0):

1) Write your animation effects as separate functions.

2) Create a repeating timed function (setInterval)

3) Within that function, every x seconds, produce a random number with a range the same as your 'effects'.

4) Use a switch statement to fire your effects functions based on your random number

Job done !